# ExpectedConstraintError In Discord.js Embed - ES6 Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm working on a Discord bot that has the functionality to list the permissions of any user in the guild. The code works perfectly so long as the user has one of the "tracked" permissions.

However, when the user has no permissions (that are being "tracked"), it should say "No Special Permissions," but instead, I receive multiple errors.

Do note that I did add a debug statement while trying to resolve the issue.

## Code Snippet:

```
if (interaction.commandName === 'user') {

    let manageUser = interaction.options.getUser('target')

    const manageMember = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(manageUser.id);

    const accountDate = manageUser.createdAt;

    const joinDate = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(manageUser.id).joinedAt;

    const joinDateTimestamp = Math.floor(joinDate.getTime() / 1000);

    const accountAgeTimestamp = Math.floor(accountDate.getTime() / 1000);

    const roles = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(manageUser.id).roles.cache
      .filter(role => role.name !== '@everyone')
      .map(role => `<@&${role.id}>`).join('\n');

    const numberOfRoles = roles.split('\n').length;

    const trackedPermissions = [
      PermissionsBitField.Flags.Administrator,
      PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageGuild,
      PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageRoles,
      PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageChannels,
      PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageWebhooks,
      PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageGuildExpressions,
      PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageNicknames,
      PermissionsBitField.Flags.MentionEveryone,
      PermissionsBitField.Flags.BanMembers,
      PermissionsBitField.Flags.KickMembers,
      PermissionsBitField.Flags.ModerateMembers,
      PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageMessages,
      PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageThreads,
      PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageEvents,
      PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewAuditLog,
      PermissionsBitField.Flags.CreateInstantInvite,
    ]

    let filteredPermissions = '\`No Special Permissions\`'

    if (trackedPermissions.some((permission) => manageMember.permissions.has(permission))) {
      const permissionsFound = trackedPermissions.filter((permission) =>
        manageMember.permissions.has(permission)
      );

      filteredPermissions = permissionsFound
        .map((permission) => `\`${permissionNames[permission]}\``)
        .join('\n');

    }

      console.log(`Permissions:\n${filteredPermissions}`)

      const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor('#aa99ef')
        .setTitle(`User Management | ${manageUser.username}`)
        .setThumbnail(`${manageUser.displayAvatarURL()}`)
        .setDescription(`### <:fairifyUser:1141513576608170004> **User ID:** \`${manageUser.id}\`
`)
        .addFields(
          { name: '<:fairifyDate:1145094016824778846> Account Created', value: `<t:${accountAgeTimestamp}:R>`, inline: true },
          { name: '<:fairifyDate:1145094016824778846> Member Since', value: `<t:${joinDateTimestamp}:R>`, inline: true },
          { name: `<:fairifyRoles:1173816294039105647> ${numberOfRoles === 1 ? '1 Role' : `${numberOfRoles} Roles`}`, value: `${roles}`, inline: false },
          { name: '<:fairifyPermissions:1173827440255172680> Permissions', value: `${filteredPermissions}`, inline: false }
        )
        .setTimestamp(Date.now())
        .setFooter({
          text: `${VERSION}`,
        });

      await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], ephemeral: true });
```

## Console Output:

```
Permissions:
`No Special Permissions`
node:events:504
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

CombinedPropertyError: Received one or more errors
    at ArrayValidator.handle (D:\Documents\Discord\FairifyBot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:473:70)
    at ArrayValidator.parse (D:\Documents\Discord\FairifyBot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:212:88)
    at EmbedBuilder.addFields (D:\Documents\Discord\FairifyBot\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:225:31)
    at Client.<anonymous> (file:///D:/Documents/Discord/FairifyBot/index.js:659:10)
    at Client.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (D:\Documents\Discord\FairifyBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:97:12)
    at Object.module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (D:\Documents\Discord\FairifyBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (D:\Documents\Discord\FairifyBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:355:31)
    at WebSocketManager.<anonymous> (D:\Documents\Discord\FairifyBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:239:12)
    at WebSocketManager.emit (D:\Documents\Discord\FairifyBot\node_modules\@vladfrangu\async_event_emitter\dist\index.js:282:31)
Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
    at emitUnhandledRejectionOrErr (node:events:383:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:85:21) {
  errors: [
    [
      2,
      CombinedPropertyError: Received one or more errors
          at ObjectValidator.handleIgnoreStrategy (D:\Documents\Discord\FairifyBot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1268:70)
          at ObjectValidator.handleStrategy (D:\Documents\Discord\FairifyBot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1121:47)
          at ObjectValidator.handle (D:\Documents\Discord\FairifyBot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1221:17)
          at ObjectValidator.run (D:\Documents\Discord\FairifyBot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:198:23)
          at ArrayValidator.handle (D:\Documents\Discord\FairifyBot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:467:37)
          at ArrayValidator.parse (D:\Documents\Discord\FairifyBot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:212:88)
          at EmbedBuilder.addFields (D:\Documents\Discord\FairifyBot\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:225:31)
          at Client.<anonymous> (file:///D:/Documents/Discord/FairifyBot/index.js:659:10)
          at Client.emit (node:events:526:28)
          at InteractionCreateAction.handle (D:\Documents\Discord\FairifyBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:97:12) {
        errors: [ [ 'value', [ExpectedConstraintError] ] ]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Normally, I can resolve the issue after some time, but this one has me completely stumped. I spent hours trying to resolve this problem.

I tried setting `filteredPermissions` to register as a String, an Array, I tried mapping "No Special Permissions" at one point, but I usually receive the same exact error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a couple of hours doing more testing into what exactly is creating the error, I discovered that the issue was caused here through process of elimination:

```
{ name: `<:fairifyRoles:1173816294039105647> ${numberOfRoles === 1 ? '1 Role' : `${numberOfRoles} Roles`}`, value: `${roles}`, inline: false }
```

The error was triggered when checking information on a user who did not have any roles in the server.

I modified how roles were dealt with, and the issue is no longer present and everything is running smoothly.

## Before:

```
const roles = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(manageUser.id).roles.cache
      .filter(role => role.name !== '@everyone')
      .map(role => `<@&${role.id}>`).join('\n');

    const numberOfRoles = roles.split('\n').length;
```

## After:

```
let roles = '`No Roles`';

    let numberOfRoles = 0

    const userRoles = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(manageUser.id).roles.cache;

    if (userRoles.size > 1) {
      roles = userRoles
        .filter(role => role.name !== '@everyone')
        .map(role => `<@&${role.id}>`)
        .join('\n');

        numberOfRoles = roles.split('\n').length;
    }
```